# How can I do this within a Simple Activity and a simple DialogFragment?

Tags: c#, xamarin, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to put a two layout with listview that is sliding from left to right and vice versa and a Page indicator of the two layout.

Just like in my picture . is it possible? I get that sample from a link here in the forum.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Could you not use a `ViewPager`? with the title of your page at the very top?

Comment: if use ViewPager, it means I will be using this Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment. But in my MainActivity. It gives me an ambiguous reference for  FragmentTransaction trasac = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction(); in my Main Activty. If I use FragmentActivity instead of Activity, I cannot use FragmentTransaction trasac = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

Comment: If you are using a support library, like the V4 library, you should use `SupportFragmentManager` instead of `FragmentManager`. But yeah, you should use the `ViewPager` to do what you want.

Comment: I am getting the ambiguous reference when I use the v4 library